# Google App Script UrlFetch not giving HTML output but JavaScript ouput

Tags: google-apps-script, web-scraping, urlfetch, view-source

I am trying to fetch content from following web page

http://www.mfinante.ro/infocodfiscal.html?cod=10376836

My code is

```
var fetchString="www.mfinante.ro/infocodfiscal.html?cod=10376836";
var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(fetchString);
```

When I view page source of above link it shows correct content but urlfetch showing different content.

In other words view source of above page shows html but urlfetch shows only javascript.

view-source:http://www.mfinante.ro/infocodfiscal.html?cod=10376836

view source behaving differently sometime shows html sometimes javascript.

Comment: There is no problem with urlfetch here, it is showing exactly what the server responds with. The server is providing javascript, and a browser executes it to build out the html content. So what you see in your browser is not what the server gave, it is a side-effect.

Comment: @Mogsdad, thanks for your comment. But please tell me how should I get  HTML

Comment: Try [this search](http://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=scrape%20html%20from%20javascript%20is%3aquestion).

Answer (score -1):

Use PhantomJS and the following js code:

```
var system = require('system');
var page = require('webpage').create();

page.open(system.args[1], function(status) {
        setTimeout(function(){
                console.log(page.plainText);
                phantom.exit();
        }, 10000);
});
```

In linux: phantomjs visit.js http://www.mfinante.ro/infocodfiscal.html?cod=5066472

In Windows: phantomjs.exe visit.js http://www.mfinante.ro/infocodfiscal.html?cod=5066472

Comment: please understand the context of questions before posting solutions. The question is related to doing web output scraping within google apps script. its not on your local machine where you can use phantomjs. your answer is completely irrelevant.

Comment: Currently, Google Apps Script does not support module imports. So the `require` method will fail here.